# On savedInstanceState getting ClassCastException

Tags: android, restore, oncreate

On savedInstanceState getting ClassCastException 
i need to get places ArrayList when calling restore function

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("places", places);
}

private void restore(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        places = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("places"); 
    }
}
```

when calling restore from  onCreate getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: it means that `places` is a `String` not an `ArrayList`

Comment: is places a field in your class? is it a String?